# Checkbox is always false in IE using javascript function

Tags: asp.net

I have a function in javascript which checks the state of checkboxes (used as labels) and sends a list of checked boxes to printing command in vb.net code.

I am calling this javascript function from ImageClick code.

Problem is state of the check boxes is lost in IE and is always False but in chrome it considers the right state.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="PrintCustName" ImageUrl="images/print.jpg" runat="server" OnClientClick = "return myFunction();" />
```

function in JS and 
Declaration of chkb is as follows;:

```
function myFunction() {

    var c1 = document.getElementById('c1'),
    c2 = document.getElementById('c2'), // Checkbox 2
    c3 = document.getElementById('c3'), // Checkbox 3
    c4 = document.getElementById('c4'), // Checkbox 4
    c5 = document.getElementById('c5'), // Checkbox 5
    c6 = document.getElementById('c6'), // Checkbox 6
    c7 = document.getElementById('c7'), // Checkbox 7
    c8 = document.getElementById('c8'), // Checkbox 8
    c9 = document.getElementById('c9'), // Checkbox 9
    c10 = document.getElementById('c10'), // Checkbox 10
    c11 = document.getElementById('c11'), // Checkbox 11
    c12 = document.getElementById('c12'), // Checkbox 12
    c13 = document.getElementById('c13'), // Checkbox 13
    c14 = document.getElementById('c14'), // Checkbox 14
    c15 = document.getElementById('c15'), // Checkbox 15

        var LblNumber = new Array();
        if (c1.checked) LblNumber[0] = c1.value; else LblNumber[0] = 0; 
        if (c2.checked) LblNumber[1] = c2.value; else LblNumber[1] = 0; 
        if (c3.checked) LblNumber[2] = c3.value; else LblNumber[2] = 0; 
        if (c4.checked) LblNumber[3] = c4.value; else LblNumber[3] = 0; 
        if (c5.checked) LblNumber[4] = c5.value; else LblNumber[4] = 0; 
        if (c6.checked) LblNumber[5] = c6.value; else LblNumber[5] = 0; 
        if (c7.checked) LblNumber[6] = c7.value; else LblNumber[6] = 0; 
        if (c8.checked) LblNumber[7] = c8.value; else LblNumber[7] = 0; 
        if (c9.checked) LblNumber[8] = c9.value; else LblNumber[8] = 0; 
        if (c10.checked) LblNumber[9] = c10.value; else LblNumber[9] = 0; 
        if (c11.checked) LblNumber[10] = c11.value; else LblNumber[10] = 0; 
        if (c12.checked) LblNumber[11] = c12.value; else LblNumber[11] = 0; 
        if (c13.checked) LblNumber[12] = c13.value; else LblNumber[12] = 0; 
        if (c14.checked) LblNumber[13] = c14.value; else LblNumber[13] = 0; 
        if (c15.checked) LblNumber[14] = c15.value; else LblNumber[14] = 0; 
        alert("printing on label " + LblNumber); 
   document.getElementById("<%= HidLblNumber.ClientID%>").value = LblNumber;

<fieldset class = "group">
legend>Select Used Labels:</legend>
label >input type="checkbox" id = "c1" name= "Lbl" value = "1"/>img src="images/Action-ok-icon32.png" onclick="clickFunction(this)"/> /label>
```

I have tried looking different posts but nothing helped. why is IE not retaining the state of checkbox after print button is clicked is my question?
help!